How can I complete Warlord achievement in 3.25?
The Warlord achievement requires to kill members of so-called war bands. I'm looking at various achievement guides (this one for example) and they all say something like this:


Redblade spawn in Lighthouse Map.
Mutewind spawn in Iceberg Map.
Brinerot spawn in Shipyard Map.
Renegades spawn in Acid Caverns Map.


However, in the current Atlas (Settlers league, 3.25) only Lighthouse map is present.
These are the ones I'm still missing (I didn't notice how I completed the others, probably in previous leagues):

Mutewind: Yorishi, Aurora-sage
Brinerot: Lussi "Rotmother" Roth
Brinerot: Musky "Two-Eyes" Grenn

Where can I find them? Are they on other maps now?

To the best of my knowledge, your assessment of the Atlas is correct: you can only encounter Redblade in the Lighthouse map. However, the wiki entry for Warband says

Warband members and associated items are still available through other means, such as certain Delve nodes...

and there are Delve nodes for each of the factions that should still be available in the Delve.
In particular,

Redblade Retreat or Redblade Base will spawn in the Magma Fissure biome,
Mutewind Retreat or Mutewind Base will spawn in Frozen Hollow biome,
Brinerot Retreat or Brinerot Base will spawn in Sulphur Vents biome,
Renegade Camp will spawn in Fungal Caverns biome.

See Delve#Nodes.

oh, nice, I will try to delve a bit and return with results!

yes, I found one, I confirm you can progress this achievement in delve
